# What version of spring does 'ehcache 2.10.1' use?

Tags: java, spring, caching, version, ehcache

I can't seem to find this information on any of their websites or forum's.

Help would be appreciated. Even if you can direct me to a forum that I could use.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look into the source. Since `v4.2.4.RELEASE` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/081905d3b380de49b633bd9f3ea714b47673e57d

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache is a library independent of Spring. As such, it has no dependency on Spring.